# MultiIndex with one of the indices as a tuple

Tags: python, pandas

I have created a dataframe with a multiindex where one of the indices is a tuple. I am unable to use .loc for indexing.

Here is the dataframe:

```
a = [['a','a','a','b','b','b','c','c'],[('one',2),('one',1),('two',1),('two',1),('two',2),('one',2),('two',2),('one',1)]]
t_index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(list(zip(*a)),names=['letters','numbers'])

b=[1,4,3,5,7,2,6,1]

df=pd.DataFrame({'position':b},t_index)
print(df)
                  position
letters numbers           
a       (one, 2)         1
        (one, 1)         4
        (two, 1)         3
b       (two, 1)         5
        (two, 2)         7
        (one, 2)         2
c       (two, 2)         6
        (one, 1)         1
```

When I try to access using .loc, I get the following error:

```
df.loc[('a',('one',2))]
"None of [('one', 2)] are in the [columns]"
```

I prefer to keep the 'numbers' index as a tuple instead of two values unless that is really not recommended. Could someone point out where I am going wrong or what should I do to access the indexes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `loc` + [`xs`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html)

```
df.loc['a'].xs(('one',2))
```

Or:

```
df.xs(['a', ('one',2)],level=[0,1])
```

**Or (more intuitive)**

```
df.xs(['a', ('one',2)],level=['letters','numbers'])
```

Output:

```
                  position
letters numbers 
a   (one, 2)         1
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also just exclusively use `xs`:

```
df.xs(('a',('one',2)), level=[0,1])
```

Yields:

```
                  position
letters numbers           
a       (one, 2)         1
```

Answer (score 1):

I just try to fix your code here

```
df[df.index.isin([('a',('one',2))])]
Out[398]: 
                  position
letters numbers           
a       (one, 2)         1
```

Answer (score 1):

If your index level `numbers` will always have two elements, I suggest you actually split the level into two.

```
tups = [(letter,) + number for letter, number in df.index]
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tups, names=['letters', 'numbers_0', 'numbers_1'])

df_ = df.set_index(idx)

df_.loc[[('a', 'one', 2)]]

                             position
letters numbers_0 numbers_1          
a       one       2                 1
```

---

Besides that, I prefer the use of `xs` with `level` as first shown by [**@rahlf23**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51596826/2336654)

Comment: Indeed the level `numbers` always has 2 elements. I ended up splitting it as the other methods were too verbose.